# How to ensure that all points are fully displayed in a polar coordinate system?

Tags: plotting

I have a set of coordinates(`Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 100}]`), which I then converted to polar coordinates, and I want to plot them, but the following code doesn't seem to work.

```
g = CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Polar", "Mapping", #] & /@
   Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 100}];
ListPolarPlot[g, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

Do all points fully display in the polar coordinate system? For example, the last point of g: $\{ \left.10 \sqrt{101},\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\right\}$

How to ensure that all points are fully displayed in a polar coordinate system?

---

Edits: By the cvgmt's answer, we made the following modifications.

```
g1 = Map[Reverse, g, {1}]; 
ListPolarPlot[g1, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 200]
```

[image]

Comment: You have to adopt the plot range to the points you want to display. E.g. g[[-1]]={100.499, 0.0996687}

Comment: The structure of data should be `ListPolarPlot[{{θ1, r1}, {θ2, r2}, {θ3, r3}}]`,not `ListPolarPlot[{{r1, θ1}, {r2, θ2}, {r3, θ3}}]`

Comment: `g1 = Reverse[g, {2}]` also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- According to the document of `ListPolarPlot`, we need to use `ListPolarPlot[{{θ1, r1}, {θ2, r2}, {θ3, r3}}]`.
- To demenstrate this,here we only plot `{10 Sqrt[101], ArcTan[1/10]}`.

```
{θ, r} = 
 CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
  "Mapping", {100, Sqrt[100]}]

ListPolarPlot[{{θ, r}}, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> .2]
```

[image]

Comment: it's a (+1) from me. good job as always. do you know why it evaluated the wrong structure of the data? seems a bit odd, doesn't it?

Comment: @bmt Thanks! Since the original  Cartesian data `{n, Sqrt[n]}` are  on a parabola `{x,Sqrt[x]}`, the final result should be also a parabola.